# A module with two dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build up a REST client written in AngularJS that uses **$resources** for consuming the REST service and **ng-grid** library for the User Interface.
By using just the $resource module dependency my code works, however if I introduce also the ngGrid dependency it just displays an empty div.
I've little experience with modules but the syntax seems correct....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-resource.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

      angular.module('myApp',['ngResource'], ['ngGrid']);
            function Ctrl($scope,$resource) {
              var restservice = $resource(
              'http://host/myapp/json', {     
               }, {
               query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
            }
          );
              $scope.gridOptions = restservice.query();
         };

  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you see any error in the above code ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Its: module('name', ['dependency1', 'dependency2'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass in a separate array for each module, nest them under one array like this.

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngResource', 'ngGrid']);
```